# Connecting folder in a Docker container with a folder on local machine - Permission Denied

Tags: windows, docker, permissions, mount

I'm new to docker and am trying to bind mount a folder in my docker container with a folder on my local machine. Using the code below, I was able to create the container with no issue.

```
docker run -it -v /Users/bdbot/Documents/mount_demo/:/mount_demo nycdsa/linux-toolkits bash
```

However, when I tried to create a txt file within the container folder, I got this error:

bash: demo.txt: Permission denied

Seeing that it was an access issue, I ran

```
sudo chmod 777 ../mount_demo
```

This allowed me to create the file, however when I checked the folder on my local machine it was not there. So the folders are not syncing.

I've also made sure the docker settings "Shared Drives" had the correct credentials. I'm not familiar enough with Docker to know how to trouble shoot further and have not been able to find anything online. I am using Windows, and everything is up to date.

Comment: `:/mount_demo` you are specifying the path which doesn't exists in the container. But you have option to get permision of the container folder with `:/mount_demo:Z` or `:/mount_demo:z` or `docker run --privileged=true .....`

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being a really simple fix. The combination of using unix on a windows machine required that I add an additional slash(/) before the folder path. The below fixed this issue for me:

```
docker run -it -v //Users/bdbot/Documents/mount_demo/:/mount_demo nycdsa/linux-toolkits bash
```